# Why does Apache run four processes?

Tags: apache-httpd

On my system running Apache 2.4 it is spawning four processes:

```
$ ps aux | grep httpd
root     18325  0.0  0.2  53448  5884 ?        Ss   10:22   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
www-data 18326  0.0  0.2 342416  4484 ?        Sl   10:22   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
www-data 18327  0.0  0.2 342416  4484 ?        Sl   10:22   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
www-data 18328  0.0  0.2 342416  4484 ?        Sl   10:22   0:00 /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -k start
```

I understand that the root process is the startup process and it is spawning a lower-privileged child running as www-data, but why are there 3 of them?

Comment: There's a bunch of MPM config settings that might be interesting to you, like MinSpareServers.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration will dictate that; barring overrides, the default [StartServers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers) value is 3 for the [worker module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/worker.html).

You can confirm by asking your httpd which modes it has loaded:

```
httpd -M
```

and/or checking your configuration, in 00-mpm.conf:

```
grep ^LoadModule 00-mpm.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache needs to spawn a process for each connection.  It's normal behavior to have multiple processes running.